# How to know if hot reload is enough or not to apply the changes in flutter app?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, hot-reload

Flutter added a very good feature, which is the hot reload I tried it several times but I noticed that it isn't working with everything for example if I changed the background color of the app and perform hot reload the color will change but there are other complex things that hot reload isn't enough for them and I must run the app again to see the changes .So my question is when I make a change in my app how to know if hot reload is enough to see the changes or not ??

Comment: https://flutter.io/hot-reload/

Comment: Maybe make a specific question asking why one case is not hot reloaded

Answer (score 0):

Hot reload repaints the whole screen once, so if you change aspects inside of your `build()`-function they should apply with hot reload, but for example changes in your `initState()` won't transfer.

So as a general advice, for smaller changes like padding adjustments, color changes etc.(mostly visual changes) a hot reload will be enough, if they don't transfer try hot restart.

If you change the code and it's functions, add new elements etc.(all bigger changes) I would recommend hot restart for safety reasons, it only takes a couple seconds anyways.